# playing a video in halfscreen meanwhile using another program in other half screen

Tags: multiple-monitors, screen

is there any way to play a video in fullscreen just using half screen and use another program on the other half? for example something like this left side playing video and right side in this case using visual studio

[image: Screenshot]

Comment: Then that would not be full screen for the video. Please clarify what you are trying to do.